# How would I install tksnack on mac?

Tags: python, tkinter, module

I'm trying to install tksnack on Mac and I installed tkinter already.

This error pops up:
`Users-MacBook-Pro:main user$ pip3 install tksnack ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tksnack (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tksnack`

I'm not sure if snack module is the same as tksnack module so I tried installing snack module.
It gave another error:

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:main user$ pip3 install snack
Collecting snack
  Using cached snack-0.0.3.tar.gz (155 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/ty/59189mt16kj5vsb0r8s4gjzc0000gn/T/pip-install-pgs3nl0v/snack_0e1a6b8c09654c4d8fbcfcbef29158cf/setup.py", line 47
          print GCC_VERSION
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: It is not good practice to install something you don't sure whether it is what you want. It is better to search more on the internet to find out the actual module you want.  Did you read clearly on the module website on pypi.org? The `snack` module you install is for Python 2.

Comment: Oops, i was trying to install the tksnack module.

Answer (score 0):

The [`github repo for snak`](https://github.com/cornelltech/snack#os-x-install-from-source-with-pip-and-homebrew) mentions the following:

> If you are on Mac OS X, you must install the real "not-clang" version
> of gcc because it has OpenMP support. At the time of writing, clang
> does not support OpenMP, and Apple has unhelpfully symlinked clang to
> `/usr/bin/gcc`. This is not sufficient.
>
> Using Apple-provided GCC is **NOT** supported. If `gcc-5 --version`
> contains the string `clang` anywhere in its output, you do not have
> the correct version of gcc.
>
> Using Apple-provided Python is **NOT** supported.

The recommended installation method on OS X is with Homebrew. The following has been tested on a clean Yosemite installation.

```
$ brew install gcc
$ brew install python
$ virtualenv venv; source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install numpy
$ pip install cython
$ pip install snack
```

> You may need to edit `setup.py` and change `GCC_VERSION` to point to the
> correct version if you are not using `/usr/local/bin/gcc-5`.

Comment: My Mac is too old so when I tried running home brew it doesn’t work that’s why I’m trying to find another way of installing it.

Comment: I see, you should definitely mention that in your question. What version of `mac os x` are you using? And what was the home brew error message?

Comment: The Mac OS is 10.12 and the home brew message was saying that version is too old and not compatible.